# Determining if Planes are Parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, cross-product

Are two planes parallel if the magnitude of the cross product of their normal vectors is equal to $0$?

$|| \vec n_1 \times \vec n_2|| = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because\begin{align}\left\lVert\vec n_1\times\vec n_2\right\rVert=0&\iff\vec n_1\times\vec n_2=0\\&\iff\vec n_1\text{ and }\vec n_2\text{ are parallel.}\end{align}

Comment: But isn't it the case that: $\vec n_1 × \vec n_2 = \{ 0, 0, 0\}$. This is why we then take $|| \vec n_1 × \vec n_2 ||$, right?

Comment: Yes, $\vec n_1\times \vec n_2=(0,0,0)$. That is what I meant. It is usual that the symbol $0$ stands for the null vector.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed:

- Two planes are parallel if, and only if, their normal vectors are parallel
- Two vectors are parallel if, and only if, their cross product is the null vector.